# How to see full Heroku stacktrace in logs?

Tags: django, heroku

When I deploy my Django app to Heroku, in the console (`heroku logs --tail -a george-paintings`)  I see an error:

```
2021-04-15T15:14:42.109272+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: No application module specified.
2021-04-15T15:14:42.161597+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-04-15T15:14:42.290903+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

But I can't figure out what particular went wrong. My `Procfile` looks like this

```
web: gunicorn --pythonpath application.george_paintings.george_paintings.wsgi --log-file - --log-level debug
```

Where can I find more info about my error?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect there's nothing more to see. A good first step would be to try running [`heroku local`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-local-processname) to see if you are having the same problem on your development machine. This will use your `Procfile` whereas if you are running via `python manage.py migrate` or similar your `Procfile` will not be used.

The error gives a good hint, though:

```
app[web.1]: Error: No application module specified.
```

Gunicorn [expects an application module name](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/run.html#gunicorn) as a command-line argument. I suspect you intend `application.george_paintings.george_paintings.wsgi` to be interpreted as your application module, but it's getting swallowed up as an argument to `--pythonpath`:

```
gunicorn --pythonpath application.george_paintings.george_paintings.wsgi  #...
```

You shouldn't need to explicitly provide a `PYTHONPATH`. Try removing that argument from your `Procfile` entirely:

```
gunicorn application.george_paintings.george_paintings.wsgi --log-file - --log-level debug
```

If this works locally with `heroku local`, commit the change and redeploy.

If not, take a look at your directory structure. `application.george_paintings.george_paintings.wsgi` is a bit of a weird module name for a Django project. Usually you'd just need something like `george_paintings.wsgi` (indicating that Gunicorn should use the Python module it finds at `george_paintings/wsgi.py` as its entry point).